# How to get os version of remote computer using computer name or ip address?

Tags: vb.net

I tried to get os version of remote computer using ip address with WMI ,It shows "RPC server unavailable" error.

If anybody have solution for getting remote system information without WMI in vbnet,
Please help me

Comment: This might be a good question to ask over on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run the SystemInfo utility as:

SystemInfo /u [servername]

And pipe the output to a textfile and then read it in your VB.Net.

Though SystemInfo might be using WMI in itself though.